# Do morphisms that are constant on the fibers of another morphism factor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, and one has morphisms $f: X \to Y$ and $g: X \to Z$, such that $f$ is constant on every fiber of $g$, i.e. for every $z \in Z$ there is a $y \in Y$ such that $f(g^{-1}(z)) = \{y\}$ .

Is it true that $g$ factors over $f$, i.e. does there exist a morphism $h: Z \to Y$ with $h \circ g = f$?

If not, what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

Let $X=Y=\mathbf P^1$, and let $Z$ be a cuspidal rational curve.

Let $f=\operatorname{id}$ and let $g:X \rightarrow Z$ be the normalisation map. Then each fibre of $g$ is a point, so $f$ is constant on the fibres.

But there is no morphism $h$ such that $h \circ g =f$, since for example $g$ is not a submersion at the point $p$ which maps to the cusp of $Z$.